# system.linq.strings is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#

I am having a problem with the last line of code because of the strings. It is giving me the error `system.linq.strings is inaccessible due to its protection level` even though I am 
using the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace.

```
private byte[] CreateKey(string strPassword)
{
    //Convert strPassword to an array and store in chrData.
    char[] chrData = strPassword.ToCharArray();
    //Use intLength to get strPassword size.
    int intLength = chrData.GetUpperBound(0);
    //Declare bytDataToHash and make it the same size as chrData.
    byte[] bytDataToHash = new byte[intLength + 1];

    //Use For Next to convert and store chrData into bytDataToHash.
    for (int i = 0; i <= chrData.GetUpperBound(0); i++) {
        bytDataToHash[i] = Convert.ToByte(Strings.Asc(chrData[i]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the line `bytDataToHash[i] = Convert.ToByte(Strings.Asc(chrData[i]));` probably doesn't do what you want it to.

You probably want your code to do something like this:

```
bytDataToHash = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(strPassword);
```

That will get you the bytes of the password.

But you are trying to use ASCII? (the `Asc` call hints to that). If you really don't want unicode, you can do this:

```
bytDataToHash = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strPassword);
```

But a better translation for that bad line is:

```
Convert.ToByte(chrData[i]); // Do not use! Will cause some data loss!!!
```

I don't know why you'd want to get the ascii value for a character in the interim though.