# system.linq.strings is inaccessible due to its protection level again

Tags: c#

I want to use the carriage-return/linefeed character combination (Chr(13)+Chr(10)).
I am using the Microsoft.Visualbasic namespace but I am getting the error

> system.linq.strings is inaccessible due to its protection

```
string Wrap = Strings.Chr(13) + Strings.Chr(10);
```

Comment: "again"?  Then you have solved this once before I assume?

Comment: possible duplicate of [system.linq.strings is inaccessible due to its protection level](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8527156/system-linq-strings-is-inaccessible-due-to-its-protection-level)

Comment: Why are you using the "Microsoft.VisualBasic" namespace if you are programming in C#?

Comment: @HenkHolterman If anything we should close that one. At least someone explained the cause this time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idiomatic way to do this in C# is `string Wrap = "\r\n";`. In this situation, though, I would simply put it in-line, like this:

```
MessageBox.Show("Encryption Complete\r\n\r\nTotal bytes processed = "
                + lngBytesProcessed, // note: no need to convert to string
                "Done",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

Answer (score 4):

The compiler can't figure out which `Strings` class you'd like to use. You can explicitly write out `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Chr(13)` to help it along. But in this case you should use the `Environment.NewLine` instead. It should get you the correct character combination regardless of your operating system.

Answer (score 3):

In C# you should use `"\r\n"` or [`Environment.NewLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

\r\n is much more concise and to the point. try

```
const string wrap = @"\r\n";
```

instead

Answer (score -1):

You are getting this error, because the system is trying to call the "String" method that is in "Microsoft.VisualBasic". For some reason it is not finding it and it is trying to call the method on "System.Linq". in your remove System.Linq if you are not using any Collections or doing anything with Linq